# How do I wait for a view to come into the view hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

My app was working until I removed some code that made a network request (so this caused a few seconds of waiting). I guess this was enough time for the view to load onto the window hierarchy... But now that I removed this network request and it goes straight to try to open that view, I get this message:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

How can I wait until the view is present before I try to open it?

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
StoreFlyersViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBar"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you are pushing/presenting a view controller (call it `A`) and another one (the `StoreFlyersViewController`) immediately, e.g. from the `viewDidLoad` method of `A` - when the view of `A` is not in the window hierarchy yet.

To solve this, you could move your code to `viewDidAppear:`. Or, if this does not produce the results you want, you could try to move the code to a separate method, and call that method via [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) with a short delay (e.g. 0.1 second).

Comment: If I put my code in the viewDidAppear, will that view ever show? Will it look like a glitch? Will the view be shown for a very very brief amount of time before the other view is pushed? Since I am calling it when the view does appear after all... I tested it and it seems not to show the view I call it in.

Answer (score -1):

try this;

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
StoreFlyersViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBar"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
    });
```

Comment: If the code was called from a background thread, this could help. But that's not the case, the app will *crash* if you call `presentViewController` from a background thread.

Comment: @Glorfindel this code is working very much fine. I've tested it.

Comment: It will certainly work, *if you call it in the right place.*

Comment: It is working. But is it safe to put in viewdidload? Will it ever fail? Will this actually wait for the view to be on the view hierarchy?

Comment: @ClaudeBastien, yes! it is adding the block in the main queue which will run after all the other methods/functions in the queue finish executing. As far as the safe is concerned, I don't think it will fail but I think you should not make the app flow like this. you should have navigated directly to the  StoreFlyersViewController without any jump. BTW this queue would not require if you present your viewController in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear.